# Can you augment/correct the answers for the given T/F questions? (real analysis-Taylor Series)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

Intuitively, I guess all the statements are true so there should exist examples for each. But I can't think of specific ones + not 100% sure of my intuition.

Can you guys provide solid examples with fully-structured steps?

** The space is strictly limited to the Euclidean one, and I need specific theorems/definitions used to validate the answers if possible, i.e., Weierstrass M-Test, properties of Taylor Series, definition of a power series, and etc.

Comment: I presume "Taylor series" should be "Maclaurin series" (i.e. a Taylor series centred at $0$).

Comment: For (a) you can take $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Also, (c) should be possible -- I can construct an example for you, if you want. About (b) I am not sure.

Comment: For (c) you can look at this math overflow link. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72/whats-an-example-of-a-function-whose-taylor-series-converges-to-the-wrong-thing

Comment: @SeanHaight It sounds like there exists one, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me provide you with an (probably unsatisfying) answer:

(a) Take $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. This function is as good as a function on $\mathbb R$ can be, i.e. infinitely often differentiable. Why does its Taylor series only have radius of convergence $R=1$? That's due to the fact that this function is the restriction of the function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C, f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ which has a pole in the points $z=\pm i$ due to the fact that $i^2=-1$. But you don't need complex analysis to see this. Just calculate the radius of convergence by one of the usual formulas.
(b) Due to the very helpful comments by Jyrki, here is an example to part (b): $h(x)=\sin(x)+e(x)$, where $e(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $x\neq 0$ and $e(0)=0$. $e(x)$ is in fact infinitely often differentiable and has the same Taylor series as $\sin(x)$, although it equals $\sin(x)$ only for $x=0$.
(c) As I learned from the link commented by Sean, (c) indeed is true.

Before voting down this answer, let me know where I can improve it ;-) Comments are welcome.

EDIT: I tidied up the answer since the OP seemed to be confused by parts of it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but as I mentioned at the bottom, the space is strictly limited to the Euclidean space; only R1, and C isn't included. Can you modify your answer based on that? Also, as you referred to Sean's link, (c) is a correct statement right? (I'm a bit confused with Prof. Shifrin's comment that one of the statement is false)

Comment: In the answer to (a), we don't use $\mathbb C$ at all -- I was just putting it there as an explanation for you, why the radius of convergence is $R=1$. Indeed checking that the function if infinitely many often differentiable and computing the Taylor series should be straightforward. About the usage of $\mathbb C$ in the answer to (b): just ignore that. What I wrote in "EDIT 3" is everything you need. Finally, the example under the link provided by Sean looks fine. Is there some part that needs clarification (besides someone saying that one answer is wrong)?

Comment: PS: The comment of Prof. Shifrin is no longer there. So he probably deleted it on purpose?

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it's just $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for (a), right? Also, which one do you think sounds clearer for (c), $e^{-1/t}$ or $e^{-1/t^2}$?

Comment: You will need to take $f(x)=\exp(-1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. About (a) you are right.

Comment: Ya I know, but $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$ was what I thought and is also referred in the link (at the bottom), which means it should also work as well as $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$. So I wondered which one do you think sounds better.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is a little easier for you since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=0$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ is only zero, if you approach it from the right. But both functions work well so that there is no mathematical reason to prefer one over the other.